# Docker inside virtual XEN Server

Tags: docker, xenserver, opensuse

I'm running Docker containers inside a virtual machine (OpenSUSE).

While running the container i'm facing lots of problems while binding ports to my containers..!

Is it  good practise to run docker inside Virtual machine..The Architecture for your reference

> Host OS --> VirtualMachine --> Hypervisor --> Server OS --> Docker

Is it a good practise..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good practise

It's perfectly acceptable practice certainly, exceptionally-common in fact.